# which kernel config to turn from module to build-in on ubuntu-mate 20.04.2 LTS

Tags: ubuntu, build, kernel, config

I have Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS where i want to run my own kernel, so I did :

```
make -j 3 allmodconfig
make -j 3 bzImage
make -j 3 modules
sudo make -j 3 modules_install
sudo make install
```

in recovery mode, the kernel panics in a softlockup
in normal mode, the kernel also does not boot
the root file system is lvm encrypted....

How to fix this ?

Comment: We are unlikely to be able to help you diagnose your soft lockup without knowing what modifications you've made to your kernel.  Are you able to build and boot a stock kernel (absolutely no modifications) for Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS on your platform with these commands?

Comment: I downloaded the kernel directly from kernel.org and did absolutely NO modiications...

Comment: Did you try asking the Ubuntu community directly?  This could be a known issue for the kernel you've picked, for something in your hardware configuration, etc.